# How often does a MQTT client check for new messages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tcp, mqtt, iot, aws-iot

I am a little bit confused about how MQTT clients receive new messages.
How often does an MQTT client poll for newly arrived messages?
For our application, we would like to connect MQTT devices to the AWS IoT Core and keep checking for messages over several days. But we want to reduce the amount of cellular data volume used for checking for new messages. Let's say, we only want to check for new messages every 5 minutes. Which MQTT parameter do I need to change?

I understand that an MQTT client does not use polling to check for new messages but the MQTT broker forwards a message to the client if it is online.
But there must be some kind of continuous check on the client-side for receiving messages, am I correct?

We know that a client sends a PINGREQ packet before the keep-alive timeout ends to let the broker know it is still alive. Does the client check for new messages during this ping?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to understand that MQTT uses a publish-subscribe messaging pattern and no request/response. So on the client side you are not asking for specific data and can define when and how often you are asking. Instead you get automatically informed as soon as there is an update to a specific topic you subscribed.

So the proper way to control the message flow is done on the publishing site - if you want a message only every 5 minutes, it should only get published with this interval.

Things are getting harder if your publishing client does publish a topic every second for a good reason but your subscriber still want to check it only every 5 minutes. In this case I think the cleanest way is to unsubscribe the topic and re-subscribe it when you want to have an update or you just disconnect and reconnect after some time.

On the technical site you usually have a blocking communication thread waiting for incoming messages which will immediately call some callback as soon as there is a incoming message. But there are also client implementations which give you the opportunity to manually perform networking actions.
This thread also handles sending `PINGREQ` and receiving `PINGRESP` but it will notice incoming subscriptions idependently (you can also disable pinging using `keepalive` of 0 but still get your subscriptions).

That being said it is no good idea to stop/restart the communication thread to control your message flow because this prevents all packages from being handled and will result in the broker disconnecting your client due to missing `PINGREQ`'s

Answer (score 0):

The MQTT protocol is already designed for low bandwidth - as long as the device is connected (sends PINGREQ regularly) new messages will be published over the TCP stream. There is no polling for new messages on the client side. PINGREQ can be sent less frequently as long as your cellular provider lets you keep the TCP connection open.

Alternatively, consider using [AWS IoT Device Shadow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-device-shadows.html), a service that can help implement a virtual representation of the device and works closer to what you described - your devices can poll this service for state updates independently of the update itself. Polling can be done using MQTT or HTTP/REST.

You will have to do some experimentation to find out which option is better suited for your use case in terms of bandwidth.